# How to set the key size for RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider from the code

Tags: c#, security, web-config, rsa

My application has a possibility to protect chosen config file. This is done using [`SectionInformation.ProtectSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx) method for specified section of loaded [`Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx). I'm using standard provider [`RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx).

The code is quite simple - very similar to [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx).

Is there any way to set the key size that should be used by provider? As I know, the default one for RSA is 1024. I need to set it up to 2048 or bigger.

The similar can be done using command line option **-size** when we use **asp_regiis.exe**. But I need to do it from the code. Maybe there is any way to configure `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` or pre-create key and inject it somehow to the default key store so next using of `SectionInformation.ProtectSection` will catch up it...

Thanks for any advice or examples.

Comment: I think you should create your own key container and then point to it, using the [keyContainerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2(v=vs.100).aspx) attribute.

Comment: Would this solve your issue, kirmir, please respond to comments.

Comment: @owlstead, probably yes. The only thing I don't like, that in this case I have to write container configuration in every encrypted config file. And additionally need to configure access rights to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider` provides two different methods.  One called [`AddKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.addkey%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can be used to create a key inside the container.  If you mark the key as exportable you can use [`ExportKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.exportkey%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method later to grab that key and store it somewhere else.

If you already have an existing key, you may be able to use the `ImportKey` method. It will accept an XML blob much like the one that comes out of `ExportKey`.

`RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` uses a default container name of **NetFrameworkConfigurationKey** if one isn't provided.  So, if you pre-create your key and add it to that container, then the provider should pick it up when you use it.

```
// Same properties as .NET uses to load the key
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
csp.KeyContainerName = "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey"; 
csp.KeyNumber = 1;
csp.ProviderType = 1;

// Create the new key, and save it in the key store
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, csp);
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
rsa.Clear();
```